ошибка при запуске собранного проекта nuxt3 на macos
Цель:
build/deploy nuxt3 проект для превью просмотра на маке.
использованные команды: yarn build > node ./server/index.mjs
данную ошибку получаю после запуска скрипта node ./server/index.mjs и перехода в браузере по ссылке проекта :
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot find module '/Users/mark/Desktop/project/.output/server/node_modules/vue/server-renderer/index.mjs' imported from /Users/mark/Desktop/project/.output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs
  at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265:11)  
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:933:10)  
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)  
  at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)  
  at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)  
  at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)  
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)  
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

in dev mode everything works fine, yarn build doesn't throw any errors, then when running node ./server/index.mjs and going to http://0.0.0.0:3000 in the browser i get error 500, i tried to install a new project with a clean nuxt app and after building the same error
в дев режиме (yarn run dev) все работает прекрасно, в процессе билда (yarn build) никаких ошибок не выдает. думал возможно в проекте допустил какие то ошибки, поэтому поставил чистый nuxt3 проект, но с ним та же проблема.
система: mac (sonoma 14.1)
node v20.12.2
